# Displaying the contents of a textfile by typing the filename in a java program?

Tags: java, filereader

Write a program that reads in a file and displays its contents. Get the input filename from the command line. For example, if your program is in the file `Display.class`, you would enter on the command line:

```
java Display t1.txt
```

to display the content file `t1.txt`.

How can this be done?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Check `Files.readAllLines`  method, it should be simple enough from there create the full program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use FileReader or BufferedReader to read the contents of file. below code may be helpful to you

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Display {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            if(args.length > 0) {

                String fileName = args[0];
                try {
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    if(file.exists() && file.isFile() ) {

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                        String line = null;
                        System.out.println("FileContents are...");
                        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("File Not Found");
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    System.out.println("File Not Found");
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Downvoted. Please don't provide a code answer to a student for a question which is clearly a homework assignment, and their question does not contain any code. As a comment for the question stated, _"StackOverflow is not a code-writing service"_.